# Auto populate Comma and Decimal in Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, number-formatting

I have a text box of dollar amount ( html below ). I am trying to add some css or jquery to auto populate comma and decimal when user enters value in the text box. For eg , if the user enters 123456789 , it should automatically become 12,345,667.89 .

```
<html:text styleId="incomePerPeriod" styleClass="textbox" property="employment.incomePerPeriod" maxlength="10" />
```

I added the below class to the html code above but it's not working. Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this ?

```
class="form-control text-right number"
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be or might not be simpler by pure JS string functions but here is a regexp version.

The thing is, i couldn't find a way to group the entered number string into `??n nnn ... nnn nnn nn` matches with regexp. However it relatively simple to get groups like `nn nnn nnn ... nnn n??`. This is the regex;

```
/(^\d{2})|(\d{1,3})(?=\d{1,3}|$)/g
```

So i reverse the string to start with as follows;

```
Array.prototype.reduce.call(str,(p,c) => c + p)
```

then applying the regex to my reversed string with `.match(rex)` would work like, `"123456789"` to yield `[ '98', '765', '432', '1' ]`.

Then of course join them with `.` and `,` at proper positions with

```
.reduce((p,c,i) => i - 1 ? p + "," + c : p + "." + c)
```

and get `98.765,432,1`. Well we just need to reverse this string again of course. So here is a working example.

```js
function formatNumber(e){
  var rex = /(^\d{2})|(\d{1,3})(?=\d{1,3}|$)/g,
      val = this.value.replace(/^0+|\.|,/g,""),
      res;
      
  if (val.length) {
    res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(val, (p,c) => c + p)            // reverse the pure numbers string
               .match(rex)                                            // get groups in array
               .reduce((p,c,i) => i - 1 ? p + "," + c : p + "." + c); // insert (.) and (,) accordingly
    res += /\.|,/.test(res) ? "" : ".0";                              // test if res has (.) or (,) in it
    this.value = Array.prototype.reduce.call(res, (p,c) => c + p);    // reverse the string and display
  }
}

var ni = document.getElementById("numin");

ni.addEventListener("keyup", formatNumber);
```

```html
<input id="numin" placeholder="enter number">
```

The `res += /\.|,/.test(res) ? "" : ".0";` part takes care of prefixing a `"0."` when we only have the cents.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I see that var ni = document.getElementById("numin");  and the line below it is places outside the function. So can you please tell me where exactly these 2 lines should be placed ?

Comment: @Soham The `formatNumber` function is in fact the callback that we pass as event listener for the `keyup` event of the input element assigned to the `ni` variable. So in another words, basically the above code is just two lines, starts from `var ni = document.getElementById("numin");` line and ends on the second `ni.addEventListener("keyup", formatNumber);` line. The function definition above is to be used as callback in the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="num" type="text" />

function addCommas(x) {
  var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return parts.join(".");
}

$('#num').keypress(function() {
  var numberTyped = $("#num").val();
  var convertedNum = addCommas(numberTyped);
  $("#num").val(convertedNum);

});
```

The script uses a regular expression to add commas. Passing a number like 23456789.12345 produces 23,456,789.12345, which is the desired result.

## Second Example

http://jsfiddle.net/ezbao2a3/15/

Comment: Do note that the number is then no longer a valid JavaScript number

Comment: Your solution will take all the number at a short and format it and that too on Click of the button. But I am looking on keyPress, the moment a key is pressed it will keep on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that formats the number `onkeyup`, in order to get the actual value of the `input`.

The `keypress` event checks for valid keys (e.g. only numbers and backspace). This could probably be perfected and moved to a js event listener.

The formatter regular expression can also be adjusted to handle decimals.

Here's a snippet. Hope it helps.

```js
isNumberKey = function(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
      && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}

var textInput = document.getElementById('txtChar');

textInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
    var n = parseInt(this.value.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
    textInput.value = n.toLocaleString();
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar" />
```

Comment: Missing adding decimals to the regex. I can investigate when possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your. I was just going through your code and wondering at what point of time  the below snippet will get called ? Because on keypress you are just calling  isNumberKey function and that ends with return true/false. I debugged and found that var textInput = .... is never getting called. Am I missing something ?                                                           
                                                                                                                
  var textInput = document.getElementById('txtChar');

Comment: You can place `var textInput...` inside the `keyup` event listener but it is initialized within the context of the snippet. You can place it wherever it makes most sense in your code. The function that is called on `keypress` checks for valid keys and cancels the event if the key is invalid (e.g. non-number, non-delete). Else it returns true and procedes with the `keypress` and subsequent `keyup` event where effectively the input is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked. Import the below line in your script tag .

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Then on onLoad function , use the below lines:

```
$('#incomePerPeriod').mask("#,##0.00", {reverse: true});
```

Comment: Glad you fixed it but unless you use masking at other places in your code, is it not an overkill to load a significantly large code just for this functionality?