# Formatting a constantly changing number with commas

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I am trying to make an increment/idle game that constantly has changing values in terms of money. I want to be able to separate large numbers using commas. E.g 1000 becomes 1,000 and so on, all while the value is till changing.

```
$<span id="money">0</span>
```

Above shows how I am using the span tag to call the money variable from the javascript. How would I make sure that this money variable stays formatted constantly even when changing?

**Edit**

```
function formatNumber(e){
var rex = /(^\d{2})|(\d{1,3})(?=\d{1,3}|$)/g,
  val = this.value.replace(/^0+|\.|,/g,""),
  res;

if (val.length) {
res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(val, (p,c) => c + p)            // reverse the pure numbers string
           .match(rex)                                            // get groups in array
           .reduce((p,c,i) => i - 1 ? p + "," + c : p + "." + c); // insert (.) and (,) accordingly
res += /\.|,/.test(res) ? "" : ".0";                              // test if res has (.) or (,) in it
this.value = Array.prototype.reduce.call(res, (p,c) => c + p);    // reverse the string and display
  }
}

var mySpan = document.getElementById("money"); 
mySpan.addEventListener("change", formatNumber);
```

I have now implemented this code into my javascript but it still does not seem to be updating the variable.

**Edit 2**

```
function moneyClick(number){
money = money + number;
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
lifetimeearnings = lifetimeearnings + number;
document.getElementById("lifetimeearnings").innerHTML = lifetimeearnings;
```

};

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281147/4543207) to see if it helps.

Comment: This looks similar to what I need but does not show how to constantly keep the format on a variable that has multiple inputs. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: You may try to insert that `formatNumber` callback to the `"change"` event listener of the span element.

Comment: How would I call a change event listener?

Comment: `var mySpan = document.getElementById("money"); mySpan.addEventListener("change", formatNumber);` and whenever the span element is updated by some means, it should format accordingly.

Comment: I've just made an edit, could you look over it and see where I went wrong?

Comment: OK i tried to correct accordingly and placed an answer which i suppose works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Either update using some variation of what [@redu pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206835/auto-populate-comma-and-decimal-in-text-box/46281147#46281147) whenever you calculate some changes to your money variable in the game's JavaScript, or</s> use setInterval() to update it every 100 or so msec.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I was slightly wrong in my comment. As i understand the `"change"` event listener is blind to the changes at the child nodes like textContent. There is in fact this `"DOMSubtreeModified"` event listener that we may take use of. So;

```js
function formatNumber(e) {
  var rex = /(^\d{2})|(\d{1,3})(?=\d{1,3}|$)/g,
      val = this.textContent.replace(/^0+|\.|,/g, ""),
      res;

  if (val.length) {
    res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(val, (p, c) => c + p)                       // reverse the pure numbers string
                         .match(rex)                                              // get groups in array
                         .reduce((p, c, i) => i - 1 ? p + "," + c : p + "." + c); // insert (.) and (,) accordingly
    res += /\.|,/.test(res) ? "" : ".0";                                          // test if res has (.) or (,) in it
    this.textContent = Array.prototype.reduce.call(res, (p, c) => c + p);         // reverse the string and display
  }
}

var mySpan = document.getElementById("money");
mySpan.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", formatNumber);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(_ => mySpan.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000), 1000 * i);
}
```

```html
<span id="money">0</span>
```

Comment: I've just tried implementing this too and unfortunately that hasn't worked either.

Comment: For this to work you have to have your span element's `textContent` updating with a pure number string. How exactly do you update your span element..?

Comment: It's being updated through functions like the one I've put has a second edit

Comment: Make sure `money = money + number;` is pure number and you may change this line as `val = this.textContent.replace(/^0+|\.|,|\s/g,"")`.. However beyond that beats me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked. How do I make sure that it is a pure number? Also forgot I have some parts updating through a window.setInterval.